# PHP MySQL Sum values of donations of all the users

Tags: php, mysql

So I have in my table entries of donations, each user has his unique identifier there and a value of donation. Now what I need to do is display top 3 donators, beginning from the one that donated the most of course. The problem is how would I go about summing all the donations of same identifier and then sort and display them?

It looks like this:

```
NAME ID   AMOUNT
Bob  0001 5
Don  0002 2
Carl 0003 10
Bob  0001 3
Carl 0003 8
```

I only know how to sum the entire donation amount, not the total for each user.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Look into [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: Use mysql GROUP BY http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: `SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table GROUP BY name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
Name, id, sum(Amount) as TotalDonation
FROM t1
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY TotalDonation DESC
LIMIT 0,3
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, it sorts properly, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html):

```
SELECT id, name, SUM(amount) as totalAmount
FROM donations
GROUP BY id, name
ORDER BY totalAmount DESC
LIMIT 3
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ac96f/7).

Comment: Thank you, works flawlessly.

Comment: Can you explain "doesnt sort"?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
Name
,id
,sum(Amount) as TotalDonation
FROM /*Your Table*/
GROUP BY name, id
```

This should work, just use your table name.

```
SELECT
Name
,id
,sum(Amount) as TotalDonation
FROM /*Your Table*/
GROUP BY name, id
ORDER BY TotalDonation desc
LIMIT 3
```

If you want to show the top donators.

Comment: this will not show top 3 donators...